# Java - How to consistently allow iconifying and moving a JFrame when it's blocked by a modal dialog?

Tags: java, swing

I've found a couple discussions about this and it's also documented here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/modality-137604.html, and this behavior seems to be platform-dependent. Has someone perhaps had the same problem and found a solution? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Could you describe the actual problem you are facing in an example? More chance for an answer.

Comment: I have a Swing application in which I use SwingWorker for long processes. When the processes are running (normally) a modal dialog is popped up to block user's interaction with the main JFrame and the components it contains. It is just inconvenient to not be able to move and iconify this main JFrame at all during a long process.

Comment: A desktop tray icon comes to mind, but that is something else. Good luck.